# Vertically centering font awesome icon with dynamic height?

Tags: css, vertical-alignment, font-awesome

First off here's what I'm trying to accomplish: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6s90H.png

But I'd like to be able to vertically center the icon regardless if the text is one line or two. I've tried using an  tag as well as using a psuedo :after element. And I've just not even gotten close. I'd like the entire area to be clickable. Any suggestions?

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/a4x8p/

```
body { background: #e8e8e8; } 
a { background: #68cdf0; 
    border: 1px solid #fff; 
    display: block; 
    color: #fff; 
    width: 200px;
    text-decoration: none; 
    padding: 5px;
} 
a i { float: right; vertical-align: middle; }
```

Comment: Have you tried `style="vertical-align: middle;"`?  I'm not so sure it'll work, but it might.

Comment: I added a code example above using vertical-align: middle; it's close but something's not quite right.

Comment: is the button height fixed, but the icon size variable? or are they both variable?

Comment: Try using display:table, see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override the class .fa using specificity and avoid using !important.

Set `display:table-cell; vertical-align: middle;` on the  the icon font element using high level of specificity for the selector in order to override the CSS properties inherited by the font-icon .fa class.

```
a i.fa.fa-caret-right { display:table-cell; vertical-align: middle; }
```

And then add  `display:table;` to the a link.

```
a { background: #68cdf0; 
    border: 1px solid #fff; 
    display: block; 
    color: #fff; 
    width: 200px;
    text-decoration: none; 
    padding: 5px;
    display:table;
}
```

**DEMO**  http://jsfiddle.net/a4x8p/4/